# How to make draggable image to appear always in front inside overflow container

Tags: jquery, css

I have problem in making my draggable image always in front,
I have no problem when my container has no overflow style 
but I need my container to have overflow-x:auto; since I have a lot of image to show:

but when I put overflow-x:auto; when I drag the image it appears at the back of its own container but expanding the overflow..

here is my html:

```
  <div id="dvSource">
 <img alt="" name="Cocolate" quantity="1" price="20.99" src="images/flavor/Chocolate.png" />
                <img alt="" name="Mint-Chocolate-Chip" quantity="1" price="40.99" src="images/flavor/Mint-Chocolate-Chip.png" />
                <img alt="" name="Triple-Tornado" quantity="1" price="20.99" src="images/flavor/Triple-Tornado.png" />
                <img alt="" name="Vanilla-Bean" quantity="1" price="50.99" src="images/flavor/Vanilla-Bean.png" />
                <img alt="" name="Vanilla" quantity="1" price="30.9" src="images/flavor/Vanilla.png" />
                <img alt="" name="Cockies-&-Cream" quantity="1" price="50.96" src="images/flavor/Cockies-&-Cream.png" />
                <img alt="" name="Cockies-&-Cream" quantity="1" price="50.96" src="images/flavor/Cockies-&-Cream.png" />
                <img alt="" name="Cockies-&-Cream" quantity="1" price="50.96" src="images/flavor/Cockies-&-Cream.png" />
                       <img alt="" name="Cocolate" quantity="1" price="20.99" src="images/flavor/Chocolate.png" />
                <img alt="" name="Mint-Chocolate-Chip" quantity="1" price="40.99" src="images/flavor/Mint-Chocolate-Chip.png" />
                <img alt="" name="Triple-Tornado" quantity="1" price="20.99" src="images/flavor/Triple-Tornado.png" />
                <img alt="" name="Vanilla-Bean" quantity="1" price="50.99" src="images/flavor/Vanilla-Bean.png" />
                <img alt="" name="Vanilla" quantity="1" price="30.9" src="images/flavor/Vanilla.png" />
                <img alt="" name="Cockies-&-Cream" quantity="1" price="50.96" src="images/flavor/Cockies-&-Cream.png" />
                <img alt="" name="Cockies-&-Cream" quantity="1" price="50.96" src="images/flavor/Cockies-&-Cream.png" />
                <img alt="" name="Cockies-&-Cream" quantity="1" price="50.96" src="images/flavor/Cockies-&-Cream.png" />
            </div>
```

and my Jquery for draggable image:

```
 $("#dvSource img").draggable({
                revert: "invalid",
                snap: "#dvSource",
                stack: ".draggable",
                refreshPositions: true,
                drag: function (event, ui) {
                ui.helper.addClass("draggable");
                },
)};
```

I search and found out this might help

```
 stack: ".draggable",
```

but still the same result my image is still at the back of the container

To make this clear see my problem image below:

[image]

and Here is my wanted Result when I drag the image:

[image]

Here is my CSS for container

```
   #dvSource
        {
            border: 5px solid #ccc;
            padding: 5px;
            min-height: 50px;
            width: 885px;
            height:120px;
            overflow-x: auto;
            overflow-y: auto;

        }
```

and CSS for image

```
 img
        {
            height: 120px;
            width: 120px;
            margin: 1px;
            border:solid gray 2px;

        }
```

Thanks in advance!..

Answer (score 0):

Jquery `draggable` with `relative` positioned elements is not always easy to work with. In your case you might want to look at `sortable`, it might work better for what you need.

https://jqueryui.com/sortable/

Apart from that, one way to solve your problem would be to use `appendTo` option, and set it to `'body'`. If your element isn't out of the overflow div, I don't think you can move it around. AppendTo will get it out, so it'll be in front of the overflow div.

But to use `appendTo`, you need to set the `helper` to `clone`. If you want to keep the effect you want, you can on `start` event set original element to `opacity: 0`, and then on `stop` set it back to 1.

It might work, but you might need some tweaking. It would look like this:

```
$("#dvSource img").draggable({
                helper: 'clone'.
                appendTo: 'body',
                revert: "invalid",
                snap: "#dvSource",
                stack: ".draggable",
                refreshPositions: true,
                start: function(event, ui){
                    $(this).css('opacity', '0');
                },
                stop: function(event, ui){
                    $(this).css('opacity', '1');
                }
                drag: function (event, ui) {
                ui.helper.addClass("draggable");
                },
)};
```

But again, you should look into `sortable`, from what I understand fom your question I think it would be more appropriate.